# Kilim with Scala: is it possible and as mature as more "standard" Scala concurrency approaches?

Tags: scala, akka, actor, gevent

Whereas I'm fully aware of Scala and Akka actors, and other, non-stdlib concurrency packages for Scala, having gotten used to [Gevent](http://www.gevent.org) (it's a green threading + non-blocking IO framework/library for Python, that has not been getting the attention I think it deserves compared to stuff like NodeJS and all sorts of Actor frameworks) and how easy it is to write concurrent code with it—just write code as if with "real" threads but no actual OS threads are used, so you can have thousands of them, like Erlang processes, and all existing code Just Works—I have to say I'm not currently too much in love with the rather limited (and somewhat hard to compose with "normal code") way in which concurrent code needs to be written when Akka-style actors are used.

Now, there is [Kilim](http://www.malhar.net/sriram/kilim/), which appears to be doing what Gevent is doing (except it's using a CPS transform not runtime stack manipulation); also, Scala is known to be able to fully interoperate with Java. However, does this interoperability fully extend to the level at which Kilim operates? If yes, what are the key things to keep in mind when a combination of Scala and Kilim is implemented? I've found some resources (e.g. https://github.com/lllazu/kilim-scala) on this by googling but nothing clear or substantial.

Note: I'd also be interested in aspects such as:

- why this is a typically discouraged approach to start with (i.e. I should be using Akka);
- that I'm wrong and Akka-style actor code isn't limiting, or is not limiting enough to have any considerable effect on the (high level) style of code;

Comment: Actually posing your question in *Feel free to have a comment on anything related, such as: long list of different topics* style automatically makes your question too broad and thus discouraged on stackoverflow.

Comment: You should look at [Habanero Scala](https://wiki.rice.edu/confluence/display/HABANERO/Habanero-Scala). A grad student I know did that for his Master's thesis, and he presented it at Scala Days a year or two ago. I'm pretty sure he's using Kilim to help with making things non-blocking. You should look at the examples to see if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I've reworded the question to eliminate/reduce the parts that are opinion based and to stress that the **core** of the question is intended to be facts based.

Comment: @DaoWen: I couldn't find any references to kilim in any of his `.scala` files even though a kilim .jar was included under `lib/`—any idea?

Comment: @ErikAllik The Kilim weaver is actually used by Habanero-Java (the java version to habanero-scala) to support non-blocking implementation of many of the parallel constructs other than actors (soon to be added into HJ). Habanero-Scala has support for actors, but doesn't use Kilim. Habanero-Scala supports non-blocking actors by simulating the blocking-receive using Data-driven futures and does not require stack manipulation.

Comment: Kilim weaving to support delimited continuations changes method signatures to add a new parameter. Kilim also requires methods to be tagged with a throws clause in the signature to help the weaver to recognize which methods to weave. This can be a problem when weaving methods which have been overridden. Since Scala code relies so heavily on traits and inheritance, I suspect the addition of a parameter by Kilim will be a problem. You could consider using the shift-reset mechanism in Scala (which includes compiler support) to get the same support for delimited continuations.

Comment: @om-nom-nom: so after my edits, what is exactly is it that is still preventing my question from being un-held?

Comment: @shams: I guess if this question wasn't still on hold, your comment could have made a great answer :)

Comment: @ErikAllik voted to reopen

Comment: Great points! I think also that u missed talking about Go- it has a great capabilities when it comes to concurrency

Answer (score 1):

> Feel free to have a comment on anything related

In C/C++ the most generic and least invasive approach to asynchronous execution seems to be the callbacks and I prefer to stay with the callbacks in order to be able to reuse the most libraries out there. With [a bit of coroutine magick](http://code.google.com/p/libglim/source/browse/trunk/test_cbcoro.cc) any callback-oriented library can be used imperatively, that is, for any method `foo (callback (bar))` I can make a wrapper `bar = foo (cbcoro)` which can be used withing a normal imperative control flow (while doing context switching behind the scene).

I'm starting another project in Scala now and going to try to use the delimeted continuations in a similar way.

P.S. Bytecode instrumentation which works fine with the Java bytecode code can still fail with the Scala bytecode, I've seen this happen with db4o and DataNucleus, therefore you need a good support (or a very good knowledge of the tools in question) if you're going that way.

Comment: My goal was that any imperative library can be used in my non-blocking/"green" code, which is exactly what gevent does, so I was hoping Kilim brings that to Java *and* Scala.

Comment: Erik, you can't use "any imperative library" with Kilim, because 1) Kilim can't replace system calls like the gevent's "monkey patching" does: JVM has dynamic bytecode loading and Kilim's weaver can't affect the bytecode that the application loads and/or generates at runtime (by JavaScript Rhino or Nashorn, for example); 2) Kilim, as far as I can see, requires the code to use Kilim mailboxes and the imperative libraries know nothing about Kilim and its mailboxes.

Comment: Good point; I just wish the question was un-held so that this sort of information could be posted as answers!